# What type should I assign if there are multiple possibilities?

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, generics, reflection

I have two classes `Class A` and `Class B`. I have made a query, say `repository.findById`. This query may return output which may be of type A or type B.

Now, class B has all the fields which are in class A and some additional fields.

I know I can write like:

```
B res = repository.findById;
```

But writing like this is can be misleading as Class A and B are conceptually very different.

So basically the problem is

```
? res =repository.findById;
```

where `?` can be A or B.

How should I solve this problem?

Comment: If A and B are conceptually very different things, then maybe they shouldn't be accessed through the same repository. You may want to consider illustrating your question with a more thorough (and more 'real-life') example, because I find it hard to understand what you are really trying to do. Right now, it feels like an XY-problem.

Comment: If class B extends class A (which seems to be the case) but class A and B are conceptually very different, you may want to re-think your application model

Comment: In the method signature of findById, what is the return type? Does class B inherit from class A?

Comment: I appreciate the accept!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like you want a base interface that both classes implement.

And note: from a puristic OOP point of view, your statements

> Now, class B has all the fields which are in class A and some additional fields.

and

> as Class A and B are conceptually very different

raise red flags. When they are conceptually so different, why would they have (and expose?!) so many similar fields?!